# IOS Swift buffer 30FPS Video for realtime object-detection

Tags: ios, swift, buffer, avplayer, object-detection

I have trained an ObjectDetector for iOS. Now I want to use it on a Video with a frame rate of 30FPS.
The ObjectDetector is a bit too slow, needs 85ms for one frame. For the 30FPS it should be below 33ms.

Now I am wondering if it is possible to buffer the frames and the predictions for a specified time x and then play the video on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already tried using a smaller/faster model (and also to ensured that your model is fully optimized to run in CoreML on the neural engine), we had success doing inference only every nth frame.

The results were suitable for our use-case and you couldn't really tell that we were only doing it at 5 fps because we were able to continue to display the camera output at full frame-rate.

If you don't need realtime then yes, certainly you could store the video and do the processing per frame afterwards; this would let you parallelize things into bigger batch sizes as well.